# I am getting an error while creating a sqoop job

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

```
Warning: /opt/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /opt/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-3.3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2022-11-06 08:26:53,928 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2022-11-06 08:26:54,565 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
```

```
$ sqoop job --create parjob -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://ms.itversity.com/nyse_export --username nyse_user --password itversity --table finalj --m 1 --target-dir /user/cloudera/fidir --incremental append --check-column id --last-value 0
```

I am getting this error when I execute the sqoop job command

Comment: There is no error shown here. There is an INFO, and a few warnings

Answer (score 0):

there is no errors showing you can check ( sqoop job --list ) whether job got created or not